# how to fix the problem of type compatibility in typescript when trying to consume a rest Api with json depth 2 +

Tags: angular8

am trying to consume a Rest Api sent from my local server using homestead to show it into my angular application though the request is sent successfully as shown in the picture but the problem is whenever i try to show it is says undefined i think the problem is cause i have json deapth 2+ and type script don't know the object type maybe .

I've tried Deserialize but didn't work

OwnerClass.ts

```js
    import { Acommodation } from './acommodation';
    import { Taxi } from './taxi';
    import { CarRent } from './car-rent';


    export class Owner {

    id?:string;
    cin:string;
    name:string;
    email:string;
    phone:string;
    accommodations:Acommodation[];
    taxis:Taxi[];
    car_rents:CarRent[];


    }
```

AcommodationClass.ts

```js
    import {Owner} from './owner';


    export class Acommodation{

    id?:string;
    owner:Owner;
    description:string;
    capacity:string;
    beds:string;
    baths:string;
    availability:boolean;
    prix_night:Float32Array;
    address:string;
    picture:string;
   }
```

myComponent.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { RestApiService } from '../Services/rest-api-Owner.service';
    import { Owner } from '../Classes/owner';
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-grid',
    templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
    })
    export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

    owners:Owner[];
    constructor(private restApiOwner:RestApiService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.restApiOwner.getOwners().subscribe(Owners=> this.owners=Owners);
    console.log(this.owners);
    }

    }
```

the prove that the Rest Api work and return Json https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BLjm.jpg

undefinded result https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXB1y.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the placement of these two lines:

```js
this.restApiOwner.getOwners().subscribe(Owners=> this.owners=Owners);
console.log(this.owners);
```

Lets assume it takes 5 whole seconds to return the data from the `getOwners()` call, during this time **javascript will not wait for the data to return**. As such the `console.log(this.owners)` will be executed right after the subscribe call is "set-up", where `this.owners` still hasn't been assigned, and thus `undefined` will be printed out. You can see this by making your network very slow using the devtools and notice that the `undefined` printout will be printed almost instantly, even tho the network call hasn't returned anything.

As with any asynchronous operation with JavaScript/TypeScript, there is the element of a "callback" that needs to be executed. There is no such thing as waiting with JS as its single threaded and can't afford to wait.

The following approaches can be used to handle async callbacks:

- [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) - the old-school approach
- [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - the more most common approach, easier to chain
- [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) - a different "syntax-sugar" approach to promises, which makes it look like the code is "waiting" but it isn't.
- [Observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) - in Angular observables are handled by the rxjs library, which are essentially promises on steroids.

Since Angular provides rxjs to handle async code, and you are already using it, I recommend changing your code to the following:

```js
this.restApiOwner.getOwners().subscribe(Owners=> {
  this.owners=Owners;
  console.log(this.owners);
});
```

This works because the log will be printed **after** the data comes back. Technically your code was always working, but the console.log was just in the wrong place, and ran at the wrong time.

Finally, I recommend reading more about how JS handles async operations in general as its a key underpinning of the language. Here is the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) on the topic